# Cannot locate a perl module

Tags: perl

I am trying to run a topology generation tool (http://informatique.umons.ac.be/networks/igen/) on linux where I need to install plenty of modules of perl.

For now, I have already installed CPAN. This tool requires a Statistics::Basic module which I also installed successfully.

However, after installing this module, the tool requires a package in this Statistics::Basic module. Here are the hints appeared in the command line:

```
Can't locate Statistics/Basic/CoVariance.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Statistics::Basic::CoVariance module) (@INC contains: /usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2/ /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.18.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.18 /usr/share/perl/5.18 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .)
```

I get confused on this request since it is already included in the Statistics::Basic module. Even though I tried to install it independently, the cpan responded this:

`cpan[1]> install Statistics::Basic::CoVariance`

`Warning: Cannot install Statistics::Basic::CoVariance, don't know what it is.`

Does anyone know how to fix it? I am new to perl so I don't know how to make it work. Thx.

Comment: the package name is Covariance (small 'v'). You need to adjust the call in the tool

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, I just try the small 'v' and get the same result.

Comment: have you installed the module?

Comment: Install `cpanm` now. It's infinitely easier to use.

Comment: you can get the fatpack of `cpanm` at https://cpanmin.us just download it and install all the programs you need. Update `cpanm` first. As @beta0x64 has pointed out, it is way easier to use and handles many dependency cases for you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace the capital V with a small v in a couple of files and you need also some other modifications. You can find [here](http://genc.tato.al/2017/10/17/igen-topology-generator-revived/) a guide on how to make IGen-0.15 work again.